# Prevent menus of a Menu control in WPF from closing

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, styles

I am trying to prevent the closing of the Menus of a Menu control in Wpf when we click out of his area.

My objective is if we for example have a Menu control in the top of the window. We then open any of the menus, and if we click somewhere in the window, the Menu closes. That is what I am  wanting to prevent from happening.

What I want is only when the click happens on  one of the Menu items, or in its header then the Menu can close...

Anyone know how to achieve this in Wpf?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [similar question](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/86075-stop-context-menu-closing/) available, here is the solution posted:

```
<ContextMenu StaysOpen="True">  
    <MenuItem Header="Expand the clicking Area" StaysOpenOnClick="True">
        <MenuItem x:Name="AreaWhereClickingWillHappen" StaysOpenOnClick="True">
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <Control x:Name="The one with the clicking stuff" />
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the [`StaysOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.staysopen.aspx) property to true

Comment: StaysOpen is a ContextMenu property. StaysOpenonclick is a MenuItem property.